# Rest api in testdrive account?

Tags: qubole

Hi I am using Qubole trial version and it is test drive account
so I am not getting API Token from control panel my accounts tab in qubole
is there a way to access REST API's Now?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

With trial testdrive account, Qubole doesn't provide the AUTH_TOKEN. You should have enterprise account to have the AUTH_TOKEN. 
As far as I know, this is as designed. unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to use ReST APIs with testdrive account.

~Mohit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Qubole Testdrive user doesn't have access to API AUTH Token. Once you unlock the free trial, you can get the AUTH Token to make API calls.

Comment: Malay, can we use Rest API with regular trail account. I am trying to connect to Qubole to read the hive tables using the examples given in qds-sdk-java. I am getting the Invalid Token response. {"error":{"error_code":401,"error_message":"Invalid Token"}}. We are using trail account.

Comment: @Ramang: Yes, you can use the Rest API for all the accounts except Testdrive accounts.

Please find the documentation link for fetching a Hive Table definition:
https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/rest-api/hive_metadata_api/get-table-definition.html

You can get the AUTH token from Control Panel -> My Accounts -> API Token -> Show.

Comment: Thanks Malay. I used a wrong end point so that Invalid Token. After using the correct end point, it worked